# Does VisualStudio support multiple GIT submodules?

Tags: git, visual-studio, gitlab, visual-studio-2019

I have a solution which is built from projects coming from different submodules.
I notice that VisualStudio2019 recognize only the the project that comes from solution repository as GIT source control. The other projects which come from other submodules does not recognized as GIT source control in VS.
What is an easiest way to manage solution with multiple submodules in VS2019?
[image]
RepC - is repository which contains solution and ProjC
RepD - is a repository which contains ProjD
**RepD is a submodule of RepC**
As you can see RepD is not recognized as GIT source control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you switch to folder view in the solution explorer, you can open the solution files for the submodules. Then VS will recognize those submodules in source control and allow you to commit to them...

I made an example, but I changed some names to "DELETE" so I'll remember to delete them later:

- RepoC & SolutionC = DELETE_Submodules
- ProjC = ProjC
- RepoD = ProjSubRepo
- SolutionD & ProjD = Delete_SubRepo...

This is how my main solution looks before and after adding the submodule project (right click the solution and add existing project):

[image: Before Adding Existing Project]

[image: After Adding Existing Project]

[image: Main Module Repo]

I then clicked to change to the folder View. I can select the top option which is "RepC" for you which will take me to the "ProjC" folder view:

[image: Change to Fodler View]

[image: Select main repo Folder View]

Once I click on the submodule's solution, I am taken to that submodule's Repo and solution:

[image: SubModule Solution]

[image: SubModule Repo]

Comment: This does not help me, I still cannot see the other submodules folders

Comment: Thank you!!!! So I must have a solution in submodule?

Comment: For sure no problem! Would you be willing to mark it as the correct answer... I think that's the only way to get it to open in VS. Otherwise, I would just press Ctrl + ` to open the command line, navigate to the submodule's directory, and manage the submodule's repo from the command line using git commands.